# How do I update a variable as the game runs?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

You see, I'm used to Pygame and the like and there was always the concept of a "main loop". Corona seems to work like a GUI, handling events more implicitly. The thing is, I have a score value:

```
local score = 0
```

And when I do something like:

```
while running do
    score = score + 1
end
```

Corona just crashes. I guess this is not the way to do this (The score gets updated as the game runs). How do I update the variable all the time? (Without touching or tapping or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "game loop" in Corona is created by adding a listener to the Runtime for [`enterFrame` events](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/enterFrame/index.html). This listener is called once per frame and can be used to update anything you like.

You could read this [guide to interactivity and event detection](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/detectEvents/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @GoojajiGreg. Try

```
local function loop( event )
    print( "enterFrame called at time: " .. event.time )
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", loop)
```